What is the proper way to use ChromaDB with python thread pool?
I'm using ChromaDB with a Python ThreadPoolExecutor with a worker count of 5. Each thread creates its own ChromaDB client for storing embeddings. However, due to thread reuse, the memory allocated for the client is not released.
embeddings = OpenAIEmbeddings()  
db_name = str(uuid.uuid1())
db_path = os.path.join("db", db_name)
vector_db = Chroma.from_documents(documents=text, embedding=embeddings, persist_directory=db_path)
vector_db.persist()
chain = RetrievalQA.from_chain_type(llm=llm,
                                    chain_type="refine",
                                    retriever=vector_db.as_retriever(search_kwargs={"k": min(5, len(text))}))

response = chain(gpt_prompt)


I tried dereferencing the object with vector_db = None, but I still have the same issue.

Your code snippet is not enough for people to approach this question - please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example - then change your code here to a minimal runnable example, including the import statements.

how did you end up solving this issue? I have the same problem
